# asp.net mvc framework, automatically send e-mail

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, email

I want my asp.net mvc framework system to send an e-mail everytime a certain action (inside a certain controller) is fired off. Are there any third party libraries or .net standard ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A more up to date method would be to use [System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) - this is the 2.0 replacement for System.Web.Mail.

Something like this, called from either a BaseController (if there are other controllers that need this) the actual controller in question.

I have the following code inside a static class to handle mailing simple plain text items from the server:

```
internal static void SendEmail(MailAddress fromAddress, MailAddress toAddress, string subject, string body)
{
    var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
                      {
                          Subject = subject,
                          Body = body
                      };

    var client = new SmtpClient("smtpServerName");
    client.Send(message);
}
```

Obviously, you'd probably want some error handling etc in there - Send can throw an exception for example if the server is refusing connections.

Answer (score 3):

Create a BaseController from which all your other controllers inherits.
In the BaseController override the OnActionExecuted Method and insert your code for sending the email.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        // Send mail here
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) Class with the other [System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx) classes are easily utilized from any *.NET* program to send mail. You just need to point it to an available and willing [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smtp) server.

Answer (score 1):

Well its not really hard to send a Email using .NET. You can just send the mail from inside your action.

But, I think we talk little about logging here, and for logging there is a range of 3th party libraries. I know there is one called Log4Net.

Most of these logging frameworks makes it possible to config how logs are stored, and porsibly also a setting to send a email, when it logs something.

But in your scenario, it would just write a plain simple mail function, that sends the mail, when the user enters the action. You can make look at: http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3096831 - its a demo of sending a mail using .NET - webforms though, but the basic things still apply to MVC.