# send email asynchronously in asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, asp.net-mvc-2, asynchronous

I need to send email in asp.net mvc 2 asynchronously after a certain action is executed.  i read this thread [asp.net mvc framework, automatically send e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461361/asp-net-mvc-framework-automatically-send-e-mail) Any further help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's a SendAsync method in SmtpClient, explained in [this video](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-send-email-asynchronously-with-aspnet).