# Contact Form EMail not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have created a contact page and contact model that has `From` `Subject` and `Message` as string values. Now when I try to send email from my development environment with code below, it won't work. I browsed around a bit looking for a solution but several things are unclear to me since I haven't dealt with this too often.

This is the method I use for sending e-mail. Commented part is also one of the attempts.
The error I get is: `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`

I realize that this probably has something to do with me being on dev.env., does it? What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Email
{
    public void Send(Contact contact)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(
            contact.From,
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContactEmail"],
            contact.Subject,
            contact.Message);
        //new SmtpClient().Send(mail);
        WebMail.Send(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContactEmail"], contact.Subject, contact.Message, null, null, null, false, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set up your smtp mail settings in web.config?

Comment: I did but here shouldn't the email come from whatever the email I type in `From`. That's the part I don't understand... Does the email actually comes from email typed in `From` or does this only state who sent it, and emails actually arrive from some prepared email address...

Comment: TBH I am using ActionMailer.NET which is really cool since I can use Views and send emails like that.  I recommend you look it up.  But, since MVC is a framework, sending emails should be pretty easy there, too; I just haven't tried it yet since I use ActionMailer.NET.

Comment: Well it should be easy... But this thing is bothering me for several hours now I wanna smash my keyboard to tiny bits... ^_^
I'll look up for ActionMailer and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you send mail like this, instead?

```
internal static void SendEmail(MailAddress fromAddress, MailAddress toAddress, string subject, string body)
{
    var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
                      {
                          Subject = subject,
                          Body = body
                      };

    var client = new SmtpClient("smtpServerName");
    client.Send(message);
}
```

Ref. [asp.net mvc framework, automatically send e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461361/asp-net-mvc-framework-automatically-send-e-mail)

Comment: I probably could but the thing is that `fromAddress` would change all the time. Wouldn't that be an issue for `smtpServer`? Do I have to create some sort of recognizer for mail typed in and generate server name or is there a more friendlier approach?

Comment: It should work since fromAddress is a parameter that you can pass anything into.

Comment: So, I don't need separate `smtpServer` for different email addresses?

Comment: I don't believe so, just go ahead and try it.

Comment: I am trying it. Not working so far. Testing out several things now. Will post back when finished with them. Tests that is.

Comment: Yep it works fine. The whole problem was that credentials to server I was using weren't correct... But you did help a lot, and I ended up using solution you proposed here. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check port number in you config file.